# Is there a model type can store tags in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to write a blog by Django, in a blog post there will be some `tags`, but I don't know which model type can implement this function.

Is there a model type can store tags in django?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [django-taggit](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-taggit) ([docs](http://django-taggit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)) to add tags to your models (e.g., your `BlogPost` model). Each model will have a field that stores these tags and there will also be an additional section in your Django admin for managing these tags.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have discussed with my colleague，He told me that I can implement it with manytomany file. and I think this is also a way.

Answer (score 6):

Three years on and, in Django 1.8, there is a field type that can store tags, if you're using Postgres: [`ArrayField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#arrayfield).

Comment: One thing to note though - this would only work if your tags are purely strings. django-taggit provides many extra features, such as the ability to have a 'through model', so you could, for example, store when a tag was added to an object, or who added a tag, etc.